# Is "semper in animi" be a reasonable translation of always in our minds

Tags: grammar-choice, english-to-latin-translation

Would "semper in animi" be a reasonable translation of always in our minds as in always remembered in a fond, personal sense when thinking about your parents?

Comment: Good question! I'd just say that it has to be *in animis* to be grammatically sound, but I don't know how well the choice of words works.

Comment: An alternative could be _in mentibus_ (please correct me if I have the wrong case). [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mens#Latin) has some examples of it being used by Virgil and Catullus, although I'm not sure if that conveys the emotion as well as _in animis_.

Answer (score 1):

How about *in corde/in cordibus*? (Cf. an expression like *ex imo corde*)

Comment: Welcome to the site and thanks for your answers! Can you edit this answer to comment on the proposed translation *semper in animi* as well? I like your suggestion, but it'd also be good to comment on the original one. The asker may have little knowledge of Latin, so explanation is better than mere statement.

Comment: In animis (non in animi, which would of course be wrong, but I suppose that's just a typo) simply strikes me a less apt (semantically, so to speak). The problem is that animus is of course a word with an enormous breadth, so referring to, say, Lewis & Short or OLD won't help all that much.